# Permission Error while in Mac OS Terminal zsh

Tags: macos, flutter, permissions, zsh

I installed flutter and I'm trying to permanently add it to my `$PATH`. However, every `$HOME` command I use, I get `Permission denied`. I have full disk access and running with `sudo` doesn't work either.

Example:

```
$HOME/ .zshrc
Permission denied: Users/myName
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute `$HOME` as a command? 'Cause it's not a command, it's a directory, and hence not executable.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! I'm new to Mac OS and still learning. I figured it out after you made it clear its not a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ nano ~/.zshrc` - add the PATH in nano editor (Ctrl-X to save)

`$ source ~/.zshrc` - to get the PATH settings for current terminal settings.

"Permission denied" is showing because file .zshrc is not executable.

Comment: More info on Flutter and Mac here: https://flutter-net.com/2020/03/25/setup-flutter-developer-environment-on-mac/